# [dom-repeat::dom-repeat]: expected array for `items`, found Object

Tags: polymer

I have the following template:

```
<iron-ajax 
        id="ajax" 
        url="backend/api.php?operacion=contenidos&idf=[[datos.id]]&len=[[len]]" 
        handle-as="json" 
        verbose=true 
        last-response={{ajaxResponse}} 
        loading="{{cargando}}"> </iron-ajax>

<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[ajaxResponse]]">
```

The AJAX response contains the following JSON (correct):

```
{
"1": [{
    "id": "6",
    "idfolleto": "1",
    "fila": "1",
    "orden": "1",
    "tipo": "carrousel",
    "titulo": "",
    "subtitulo": null,
    "color1": null,
    "color2": null,
    "color_fondo": null
}],
"2": [{
    "id": "7",
    "idfolleto": "1",
    "fila": "2",
    "orden": "1",
    "tipo": "texto-imagenes",
    "titulo": "Texto 1",
    "subtitulo": null,
    "color1": null,
    "color2": null,
    "color_fondo": null
}, {
    "id": "8",
    "idfolleto": "1",
    "fila": "2",
    "orden": "2",
    "tipo": "texto-imagenes",
    "titulo": "Texto 2",
    "subtitulo": null,
    "color1": null,
    "color2": null,
    "color_fondo": null
}],
"3": [{
    "id": "9",
    "idfolleto": "1",
    "fila": "3",
    "orden": "3",
    "tipo": "texto-imagenes",
    "titulo": "Texto 3",
    "subtitulo": null,
    "color1": null,
    "color2": null,
    "color_fondo": null
}]
}
```

But I get an error:

> `[dom-repeat::dom-repeat]`: expected array for `items`, found `Object {1: Array[1], 2: Array[2], 3: Array[1]}`

Why?
Thanks!

Comment: The error message is correct - the "root object" is not array (ie wrapped by `[]`) but object (wrapped by `{}`)

Comment: But other similar service response with similar object wrapped by {} and it is working

Comment: @Jaime I've moved your PHP code into your new [tag:php] question.

Answer (score 1):

The server is sending a large object instead of an array. If you have control of the service, you should convert the object into an array server-side before sending it to the client (more efficient, less wasted bandwidth).

If you can't (or don't want to) modify the service, you could perform the conversion in the client. This gives you the opportunity to map-reduce the dataset, discarding data that is unneeded in your views.

Here are a couple options:

- Use an [observer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/observers#simple-observers) on `ajaxResponse` that sets another property, bound in the repeater (e.g., `_data`).

  ```
  // template
  <iron-ajax
          url="backend/api.php?operacion=contenidos&idf=[[datos.id]]&len=[[len]]" 
          last-response="{{ajaxResponse}}">
  </iron-ajax>

  <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[_data]]">...</template>

  // script
  Polymer({
    properties: {
      ajaxResponse: {
        type: Object,
        observer: '_ajaxResponseChanged'
      },

      _data: Array
    },

    _ajaxResponseChanged: function(r) {
      // get data of type 'texto-imagenes' only
      this._data = Object.keys(r)
                         .map(key => ({key, values: r[key].filter(v => v.tipo === 'texto-imagenes')}))
                         .filter(x => x.values.length);
    },
    ...
  });
  ```
- Use a [computed property](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/observers#define-a-computed-property) or [computed binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#annotated-computed) which computes the dataset based on `ajaxResponse`.

  ```
  // template
  <iron-ajax
          url="backend/api.php?operacion=contenidos&idf=[[datos.id]]&len=[[len]]" 
          last-response="{{ajaxResponse}}">
  </iron-ajax>

  // computed property
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[_data]]">...</template>

  // OR computed binding
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[_computeData(ajaxResponse)]]">...</template>

  // script
  Polymer({
    properties: {
      ajaxResponse: Object,

      _data: {
        computed: '_computeData(ajaxResponse)'
      }
    },

    _computeData: function(r) {
      // get data of type 'texto-imagenes' only
      return Object.keys(r)
                   .map(key => ({key, values: r[key].filter(v => v.tipo === 'texto-imagenes')}))
                   .filter(x => x.values.length);
    },
    ...
  });
  ```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EuQpJzLH89xlohr76NZt?p=preview)

Comment: I have edited my post to write about my server-side service

Comment: Ok. The service implementation isn't pertinent to this question (which is strictly about your Polymer code). You should ask that as a new question with the [tag:php] tag so that PHP devs could help you out.

Comment: I have created a new post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40831792/php-service-for-an-iron-ajax-request