# How do I create a JSON-encoded 2D array?

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a two-dimensional array with the following code, but it gets JSON-encoded as an object. How do I fix this?

```
$result = $bd->query("select * from contenidos where idfolleto=$idf order by fila");
$arr = array();

if ($result) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
        $filaAct = $row->fila;
        $arr[$filaAct][] = (array) $row;
    }
}      

echo json_encode($arr);
```

The output is:

```
{
"1": [{
    "id": "6",
    "idfolleto": "1",
    "fila": "1",
    "orden": "1",
    "tipo": "carrousel",
    "titulo": "",
    "subtitulo": null,
    "color1": null,
    "color2": null,
    "color_fondo": null
}],
"2": [{
    "id": "7",
    "idfolleto": "1",
    "fila": "2",
    "orden": "1",
    "tipo": "texto-imagenes",
    "titulo": "Texto 1",
    "subtitulo": null,
    "color1": null,
    "color2": null,
    "color_fondo": null
}, {
    "id": "8",
    "idfolleto": "1",
    "fila": "2",
    "orden": "2",
    "tipo": "texto-imagenes",
    "titulo": "Texto 2",
    "subtitulo": null,
    "color1": null,
    "color2": null,
    "color_fondo": null
}],
"3": [{
    "id": "9",
    "idfolleto": "1",
    "fila": "3",
    "orden": "3",
    "tipo": "texto-imagenes",
    "titulo": "Texto 3",
    "subtitulo": null,
    "color1": null,
    "color2": null,
    "color_fondo": null
}]
}
```

Comment: If you want to get back an array then try `json_decode($arr, true)`. You'll get an array of arrays not objects.

Comment: But json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string

Answer (score 2):

You would have to index it without using your own defined indices.

If you must maintain using `fila` as the indices then you have to understand that the encoded JSON will be an object. You can json_decode it back into an array though like: `json_decode($json, 1);`

Otherwise before encoding the array you could call: `$arr = array_values($arr);` which would result in the array being encoded as a JSON array once you call `json_encode`.

Comment: I think I'm going to review my implementation and avoid "fila" as indexes.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you're sure that your `fila` fields will contain "indexes" (I mean continuous integers starting from 0), then you can convert them to integers using `intval`.

```
if ($result) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
        $arr[intval($row->fila)][] = (array) $row;
    }
}
```

Otherwise, it probably would be better to just group the records and create an array of the groups.

```
if ($result) {
    $groups = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
        $groups[$row->fila][] = (array) $row;
    }
    $arr = array_values($groups);
}
```

Comment: I think I'm going to review my implementation and avoid "fila" as indexes. Thanks!