# Polymer nested dom-repeat expected array error

Tags: polymer

From this iron-ajax element:

```
<iron-ajax 
   id="ajax" 
   url="..." 
   handle-as="json" 
   verbose=true 
   last-response={{ajaxResponse}} 
   loading="{{cargando}}"> 
</iron-ajax>
```

I get this iron-ajax response:

```
{
    "id": "3",
    "idcontenido": "9",
    "imagenes": ["oneimage.png", "anotherimage.png"],
    "tipo_imagen": "img-circle",
    "html": "Lorem ipsum"
}
```

And I need to implement a nested dom-repeat structure in order to iterate items from imagenes attribute. This is my code:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[ajaxResponse]]" as="registro">
   <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[registro.imagenes]]" as="imagen">
      <img class="[[registro.tipo_imagen]]" src="img/[[imagen]]" alt="" width="140" height="140" />
   </template>
</template>
```

But I get this error:

> [dom-repeat::dom-repeat]: expected array for 'items', found Object {id: "3", idcontenido: "9", imagenes: Array[2], tipo_imagen: "img-circle", html: "Lorem ipsum"}

Why?
Thanks!

Comment: The response that you are getting is not an array, its an object and dom-repeat works only with Array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\[dom-repeat::dom-repeat\]: expected array for \`items\`, found Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40824121/dom-repeatdom-repeat-expected-array-for-items-found-object)

Answer (score 1):

The [`<dom-repeat>`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/dom-repeat) can only iterate over [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)s, so you can't pass [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)s to it. You're seeing the `expected array` error message because you're binding `<dom-repeat>.items` to `ajaxResponse`, which is an object.

In the [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40824121/dom-repeatdom-repeat-expected-array-for-items-found-object), your service was sending an object of array items:

```
{
   "1": [{"id": "1"}, {"id": "2"}],
   "2": [{"id": "3"}],
   ...
}
```

instead of an array:

```
[
   [{"id": "1"}, {"id": "2"}],
   [{"id": "3"}],
   ...
]
```

In this question, your service is sending a single item object:

```
{"id": "1"}
```

instead of an array:

```
[{"id": "1"}]
```

If `ajaxResponse` is really supposed to be a single item object, you could fix your template by just removing the outer `<dom-repeat>`, binding directly to `ajaxResponse.imagenes`:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[ajaxResponse.imagenes]]" as="imagen">
  <img class="[[registro.tipo_imagen]]" src="img/[[imagen]]" alt="" width="140" height="140" />
</template>
```

On the other hand, if `ajaxResponse` is supposed to be an array, you'll need to either fix that in your service, or convert it in the client, using the techniques I described in the [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40824121/dom-repeatdom-repeat-expected-array-for-items-found-object).